# How can I remove (trim) the kB from the storage values

Tags: linux

The output spits some disk usage values in xxxxxkB. How can I remove the kB from each value?

```
 df -B KB | awk 'NR!=1&&$1!~/tmpfs|cdrom/{printf "'$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")','$(hostname)',%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $2, $3, $4, $1}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a sed command to replace kB with empty string

`sed -e 's/kB//g'`

This will do :

```
df -B KB | awk 'NR!=1&&$1!~/tmpfs|cdrom/{printf "'$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")','$(hostname)',%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $2, $3, $4, $1}' | sed -e 's/kB//g'
```

Comment: Can there be multiple sed in the same string? For example $4 I believe is xx% I'd like to get rid of the percentage sign and kB.

Comment: Sure you can add another pipped sed -e 's/%kB//g'

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!